Search an xml-file with linq to xml and manipulate attribute
Actually I'm trying to change the Attribute of one of my Elements in a xml file. Still I fail to select the elements in my xml file. My xml file looks like that (shortened):
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<settingData xmlns="head.de">
  <version>4.9.2.1</version>
  <setting name="strEdmServiceUrl" value="" />
</settingData>

The error which is raised is a null-reference when I try to select my elements with xelDllSettings.Element( "settingData" ). I already checked that xelDllSettings is actually my xml file.
So far my code to manipulate the xml file looks like that:
String strEdmServiceUrl = "Text to add in value attribute";
XElement xelDllSettings = XElement.Load( CORRECT_FILEPATH );
xelDllSettings.Element( "settingData" ).Elements( "setting" ).FirstOrDefault( att => ( String )att.Attribute( "value" ) == "strEdmServiceUrl" ).SetAttributeValue( "value", strEdmServiceUrl );
xelDllSettings.Save( CORRECT_FILEPATH, SaveOptions.None );

How do I access the correct Element (selected by the "name" attribute) and change the value of the "value" attribute?

You need to include the namespace.

PLease try the following solution that is using LINQ to XML API. It is available in the .Net Framework since 2007.
c#
void Main()
{
    const string FILENAME = @"e:\Temp\DevEV.xml";
    const string NEW_FILENAME = @"e:\Temp\DevEV_new.xml";

    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

    XNamespace ns = xdoc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();

    var attr = xdoc.Descendants(ns + "setting")?
        .Where(d => (string)d.Attribute("name")?.Value == "strEdmServiceUrl")
        .FirstOrDefault()?.Attribute("value");
    attr.Value = "999";

    Console.WriteLine(xdoc);
    xdoc.Save(NEW_FILENAME);
}

Output
<settingData xmlns="head.de">
  <version>4.9.2.1</version>
  <setting name="strEdmServiceUrl" value="999" />
</settingData>


Perfect, that worked for me! Thank you.
